# SQLite Exception no such column when trying to select

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following DB helper class:

```
public int studentExists(String studid) {
    Cursor dataCount = mDb.rawQuery("select count(*) from usertable where " + KEY_STUDID + "=" + studid, null);
    dataCount.moveToFirst();
    int count = dataCount.getInt(0);
    dataCount.close();
    return count;
}
```

I use this in my app to see if a student id has been previously entered.

This works fine when the student id's are ints (346742) but whenever I try to add an alpha-numeric id (PB3874) it force closes the app.

Error:

> 06-13 18:22:20.554: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8088): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: pb3874: , while compiling: select count(*) from usertable where studid=pb3874

I don't think its a data type issue (because I use the text type):

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table usertable (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "studid text not null);";
```

But I'm confused why the error is saying `no such column: pb3874` as I'm trying to simply select that value from the studid column.  And also why this works perfectly for any int value.  Anyone have any problem solving advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite insert issue – Error: no such column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958789/sqlite-insert-issue-error-no-such-column)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

What's happening here is that SQLite thinks that 'pb3874' is actually a column name, rather than a string/text literal.

To specify that it's a text literal, you'll want to ensure your text value is wrapped in the appropriate single quotes:

To prevent SQL injection attacks, whenever you're taking input from the user, use a parameterized query:

```
("select count(*) from usertable where " + KEY_STUDID + "=?", studid);
```

Without parameterization (very much discouraged when taking user input):

```
("select count(*) from usertable where " + KEY_STUDID + "='" + studid + "'", null);
```

The reason your numeric values didn't produce this: SQLite converted those numeric literals for you.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped to debug an issue for me. Forgot to include single quotes for string and got the same SQLiteException.

Comment: @p.campbell Thanks a lot

Comment: Very Useful Answer, Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 7):

You need to quote 'pb3874' (single quotes) if you are including it in the SQL string.

Answer (score 2):

I think you got the answer to what's wrong from Antlersoft or p.campbell, to format the query correctly, I would suggest, you do it like this :

```
mDb.rawQuery("select count(*) from usertable where " + KEY_STUDID + "=?", studid);
```

That should (1) solve your problem and (2) protect you from SQL injections

Also, I am not sure that

```
dataCount.getInt(0);
```

is the best thing to do... you should probably use `getColumnIndex` to make sure you are getting the right data...

Comment: +1 agreed. Thanks Matt. I'll shamelessly add the parameterization to my answer in hopes that future Android SQLite visitors to this page will get the benefit of the SQL injection prevention. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for STRING you should place that in between '' ('sasas')

```
select * from bio where email = 'sasas'
```

Answer (score -1):

Error was in trigger being fired on database update