# SQLite insert issue – Error: no such column

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-insert, parse-error

I faced an issue with SQLite (version 3.7.13 if matters).

I created a new table with two columns `foo` and `bar`, data type is undefined. When I try to insert numbers, it works fine. But when I insert text, `Error: no such column` happens.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (foo, bar);
sqlite> .tables
test
sqlite> insert into test values (0,1);
sqlite> select * from test;
0|1
sqlite> insert into test values (a,b);
Error: no such column: a
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to quote strings

```
insert into test values('a', 'b')
```

Comment: Or to use placeholders (e.g., `?`) if executing the `INSERT` in a context that can supply the values more efficiently, such as any embedded use of SQLite (but not the sqlite shell IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> Parse error: no such column: John

Because I used `""` for the value `John` as shown below:

```sql
                                  ↓    ↓
INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES ("John");
```

So, I used `''` for the value `John` as shown below, then the error was solved. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603572/escape-single-quote-character-for-use-in-an-sqlite-query/77212862#77212862) explains it more:

```sql
                                  ↓    ↓
INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES ('John');
```