# Im getting SQLITE_Error: no such column, but it exists why?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, discord

Im trying to get the rowid from the database where there is someone with the same username from the guy who just wrote a message. The code works when I change

```
 WHERE creator` =${member.username} to WHERE matchid =` ${matchid}.
```

It gets me the rowid from that match. But I want to get the rowids from where the user is the creator. (I checked my db and on the creator column there is the name of the username Boanak). The error that im getting is this: { Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: Boanak errno: 1, code: 'SQLITE_ERROR' }.

My code:

```
var getMatchid = function(client, message, callback) {
  //let matchid = parseInt(args.join(' '));
  let member= message.member.user;
  var db = new sqlite3.Database('Matches');
  db.serialize(function() {
      db.all(`SELECT rowid
        FROM Match
        WHERE creator =`+${member.username}, function(err, allRows){
          if(err) {
              //console.log(err);
              callback(err, null);
          }
          else {
              callback(null, allRows);
          }
          db.close();
      });
  });
  }

getMatchid(client, message, function(err, data){
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
  else if (data && data.length) {
      message.channel.send(`Match ${data[0].rowid} found`);

  }
  else {
      message.channel.send("That match ID doesnt exist.");
  }
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite insert issue – Error: no such column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958789/sqlite-insert-issue-error-no-such-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encapsulate your variable in a string.  You're also using template literals, so you can put the expression directly inside.

```
`SELECT rowid
 FROM Match
 WHERE creator = "${member.username}"`
```

Comment: Wow! Something so easy! Thanks alot!