# Sqlite how to update if new value is smaller then the value in database

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I have a database where you can enter names and times, but the time is updated, and I just wanted to update the database when the new time is smaller than the time it was already in the database .

For example:

My DB:

```
ID   TeamName   TeamTime

1     Team 1     3 sec.

2     Team 2     9 sec.

3     Team 3     4 sec.
```

New time of Team 1 = 5 sec.

```
if (new_time_team_1 < team_1_actual_time) {
    myDb.update(to_new_time);
}
```

How can I do this?

This is my DatabaseHelper code:

```
package com.example.caca_a_frase;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BaseDeDados extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Caca_a_Frase.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Top5";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "NOME";
public static final String COL_3 = "TEMPO";

public BaseDeDados(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NOME TEXT UNIQUE,TEMPO INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String equipa,String tempo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,equipa);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,tempo);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public ArrayList<String> getEquipas() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> nomeEquipas = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_2 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + COL_3 + " ASC", null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();


        do {
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_2));

            nomeEquipas.add(name);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return nomeEquipas;

}

public ArrayList<String> getTempo() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> melhorTempo = new ArrayList<String>();
    String orderBy = BaseDeDados.COL_3 + " ASC";
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, orderBy);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();


        do {
            String tempo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_3));

            melhorTempo.add(tempo);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return melhorTempo;

}

public void updateTempo(String nome_equipa, String novo_tempo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COL_3, novo_tempo);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, args, "NOME = ?", new String[]{nome_equipa});
}

}
```

I hope I explained it well.

**UPDATE**

I updated my code.
I decided to use a cursor that would fetch the team's old time and compare it with the new time to do the update, but he is giving me an error.
This is the LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.caca_a_frase, PID: 19421
              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Jessica (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT TEMPO FROM Top5 WHERE NOME = Jessica
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1093)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:670)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1440)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1379)
                  at com.example.caca_a_frase.BaseDeDados.updateTempo(BaseDeDados.java:103)
                  at com.example.caca_a_frase.Game$4.onClick(Game.java:717)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

And this is the code:

```
public void updateTempo(String nome_equipa, String novo_tempo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COL_3, novo_tempo);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_3 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + " = " + nome_equipa, null);
    String tempo_antigo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_3));
    Integer new_time = Integer.parseInt(novo_tempo);
    Integer old_time = Integer.parseInt(tempo_antigo);
    if (new_time < old_time) {
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, args, "NOME = ?", new String[]{nome_equipa});
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I went to see the answer of this question ([SQLite Exception no such column when trying to select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337296/sqlite-exception-no-such-column-when-trying-to-select)) and still gives an error.

Here is the LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.caca_a_frase, PID: 8731
              android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
                  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
                  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
                  at com.example.caca_a_frase.BaseDeDados.updateTempo(BaseDeDados.java:104)
                  at com.example.caca_a_frase.Game$4.onClick(Game.java:717)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Here is the new code:

```
 public void updateTempo(String nome_equipa, String novo_tempo) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(COL_3, novo_tempo);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_3 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + " =?", new String[]{nome_equipa});
    String tempo_antigo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_3));
    Integer new_time = Integer.parseInt(novo_tempo);
    Integer old_time = Integer.parseInt(tempo_antigo);
    if (new_time < old_time) {
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, args, "NOME = ?", new String[]{nome_equipa});
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the old time. Compare it against the new time. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to read the old time, that's the problem.

Comment: And what are your `get` functions doing?

Comment: The `getTempo()` get's all the times of all the teams, but I just want one time of a certain team.

Comment: Read any basic SQL tutorial.

Comment: Already searched for tutorials, but what I find is how to read all the values of one column, and what I want is to read the value of the team.
For example:
In the table of the question I want to know the time of Team 2.
I can't find a tutorial that says how to do it.

Comment: [example tutorial](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-where-clause.htm)

Comment: I updated my code with the example tutorial you gave me, but it's giving me an error. I updated the question.

Comment: Updated the question again. Now it's giving me a different error. The LogCat is in the question update.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like

```
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
int id = bla bla
String time = bla bla

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("TeamName", time);
db.update("yourTableName", contentValues, "ID = "+id,null);
```

as `id` is your row id, and `time` is your new time value