# Getting "SQLiteException: no such column" in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, dbflow

I am using DBflow in my application right now and I wanted to modify a table by inserting a new column called `categoryId`. So I searched a little bit and I found out that I had to write a migration script to handle this modification in my table "Task". The problem is that I don't know what went wrong, but I got an error saying that there was no such column.

I uninstalled the app and install it back again and it worked just fine. The problem is that I have some other users getting the same error and I don't know what is causing it.

```
/**
 * This is generated code. Please do not modify */
public final class Task_Table extends ModelAdapter<Task> {
  /**
   * Primary Key */
  public static final Property<String> id = new Property<String>(Task.class, "id");

  public static final Property<String> project_id = new Property<String>(Task.class, "project_id");

  public static final Property<String> title = new Property<String>(Task.class, "title");

  public static final Property<String> description = new Property<String>(Task.class, "description");

  public static final Property<String> collection_id = new Property<String>(Task.class, "collection_id");

  public static final Property<Integer> priority = new Property<Integer>(Task.class, "priority");

  public static final TypeConvertedProperty<Long, Date> created_at = new TypeConvertedProperty<Long, Date>(Task.class, "created_at", true,
  new TypeConvertedProperty.TypeConverterGetter() {
  @Override
  public TypeConverter getTypeConverter(Class<?> modelClass) {
    Task_Table adapter = (Task_Table) FlowManager.getInstanceAdapter(modelClass);
  return adapter.global_typeConverterDateConverter;
  }
  });

  public static final Property<String> created_by = new Property<String>(Task.class, "created_by");

  public static final TypeConvertedProperty<Long, Date> updated_at = new TypeConvertedProperty<Long, Date>(Task.class, "updated_at", true,
  new TypeConvertedProperty.TypeConverterGetter() {
  @Override
  public TypeConverter getTypeConverter(Class<?> modelClass) {
    Task_Table adapter = (Task_Table) FlowManager.getInstanceAdapter(modelClass);
  return adapter.global_typeConverterDateConverter;
  }
  });

  public static final TypeConvertedProperty<Long, Date> due_date = new TypeConvertedProperty<Long, Date>(Task.class, "due_date", true,
  new TypeConvertedProperty.TypeConverterGetter() {
  @Override
  public TypeConverter getTypeConverter(Class<?> modelClass) {
    Task_Table adapter = (Task_Table) FlowManager.getInstanceAdapter(modelClass);
  return adapter.global_typeConverterDateConverter;
  }
  });

  public static final TypeConvertedProperty<Long, Date> completed_at = new TypeConvertedProperty<Long, Date>(Task.class, "completed_at", true,
  new TypeConvertedProperty.TypeConverterGetter() {
  @Override
  public TypeConverter getTypeConverter(Class<?> modelClass) {
    Task_Table adapter = (Task_Table) FlowManager.getInstanceAdapter(modelClass);
  return adapter.global_typeConverterDateConverter;
  }
  });

  public static final Property<String> completed_by = new Property<String>(Task.class, "completed_by");

  public static final Property<String> categoryId = new Property<String>(Task.class, "categoryId");

  public static final Property<Integer> feed_count = new Property<Integer>(Task.class, "feed_count");

  public static final Property<Integer> read_count = new Property<Integer>(Task.class, "read_count");

  public static final IProperty[] ALL_COLUMN_PROPERTIES = new IProperty[]{id,project_id,title,description,collection_id,priority,created_at,created_by,updated_at,due_date,completed_at,completed_by,categoryId,feed_count,read_count};

  private final DateConverter global_typeConverterDateConverter;

  public Task_Table(DatabaseHolder holder, DatabaseDefinition databaseDefinition) {
    super(databaseDefinition);
    global_typeConverterDateConverter = (DateConverter) holder.getTypeConverterForClass(Date.class);
  }

  @Override
  public final Class<Task> getModelClass() {
    return Task.class;
  }

  @Override
  public final String getTableName() {
    return "`Task`";
  }

  @Override
  public final Task newInstance() {
    return new Task();
  }

  @Override
  public final Property getProperty(String columnName) {
    columnName = QueryBuilder.quoteIfNeeded(columnName);
    switch ((columnName)) {
      case "`id`":  {
        return id;
      }
      case "`project_id`":  {
        return project_id;
      }
      case "`title`":  {
        return title;
      }
      case "`description`":  {
        return description;
      }
      case "`collection_id`":  {
        return collection_id;
      }
      case "`priority`":  {
        return priority;
      }
      case "`created_at`":  {
        return created_at;
      }
      case "`created_by`":  {
        return created_by;
      }
      case "`updated_at`":  {
        return updated_at;
      }
      case "`due_date`":  {
        return due_date;
      }
      case "`completed_at`":  {
        return completed_at;
      }
      case "`completed_by`":  {
        return completed_by;
      }
      case "`categoryId`":  {
        return categoryId;
      }
      case "`feed_count`":  {
        return feed_count;
      }
      case "`read_count`":  {
        return read_count;
      }
      default: {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid column name passed. Ensure you are calling the correct table's column");
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public final IProperty[] getAllColumnProperties() {
    return ALL_COLUMN_PROPERTIES;
  }

  @Override
  public final void bindToInsertValues(ContentValues values, Task model) {
    values.put("`id`", model.getId() != null ? model.getId() : null);
    values.put("`project_id`", model.getProjectId() != null ? model.getProjectId() : null);
    values.put("`title`", model.getTitle() != null ? model.getTitle() : null);
    values.put("`description`", model.getDescription() != null ? model.getDescription() : null);
    values.put("`collection_id`", model.getCollectionId() != null ? model.getCollectionId() : null);
    values.put("`priority`", model.getPriority());
    Long refmCreatedAt = model.getCreatedAt() != null ? global_typeConverterDateConverter.getDBValue(model.getCreatedAt()) : null;
    values.put("`created_at`", refmCreatedAt != null ? refmCreatedAt : null);
    values.put("`created_by`", model.getCreatedById() != null ? model.getCreatedById() : null);
    Long refmUpdatedAt = model.getUpdatedAt() != null ? global_typeConverterDateConverter.getDBValue(model.getUpdatedAt()) : null;
    values.put("`updated_at`", refmUpdatedAt != null ? refmUpdatedAt : null);
    Long refmDueDate = model.getDueDate() != null ? global_typeConverterDateConverter.getDBValue(model.getDueDate()) : null;
    values.put("`due_date`", refmDueDate != null ? refmDueDate : null);
    Long refmCompletedAt = model.getCompletedAt() != null ? global_typeConverterDateConverter.getDBValue(model.getCompletedAt()) : null;
    values.put("`completed_at`", refmCompletedAt != null ? refmCompletedAt : null);
    values.put("`completed_by`", model.getCompletedById() != null ? model.getCompletedById() : null);
    values.put("`categoryId`", model.getCategoryId() != null ? model.getCategoryId() : null);
    values.put("`feed_count`", model.getFeedCount());
    values.put("`read_count`", model.getReadCount());
  }

  @Override
  public final void bindToInsertStatement(DatabaseStatement statement, Task model, int start) {
    statement.bindStringOrNull(1 + start, model.getId());
    statement.bindStringOrNull(2 + start, model.getProjectId());
    statement.bindStringOrNull(3 + start, model.getTitle());
    statement.bindStringOrNull(4 + start, model.getDescription());
    statement.bindStringOrNull(5 + start, model.getCollectionId());
    statement.bindLong(6 + start, model.getPriority());
    Long refmCreatedAt = model.getCreatedAt() != null ? global_typeConverterDateConverter.getDBValue(model.getCreatedAt()) : null;
    statement.bindNumberOrNull(7 + start, refmCreatedAt);
    statement.bindStringOrNull(8 + start, model.getCreatedById());
    Long refmUpdatedAt = model.getUpdatedAt() != null ? global_typeConverterDateConverter.getDBValue(model.getUpdatedAt()) : null;
    statement.bindNumberOrNull(9 + start, refmUpdatedAt);
    Long refmDueDate = model.getDueDate() != null ? global_typeConverterDateConverter.getDBValue(model.getDueDate()) : null;
    statement.bindNumberOrNull(10 + start, refmDueDate);
    Long refmCompletedAt = model.getCompletedAt() != null ? global_typeConverterDateConverter.getDBValue(model.getCompletedAt()) : null;
    statement.bindNumberOrNull(11 + start, refmCompletedAt);
    statement.bindStringOrNull(12 + start, model.getCompletedById());
    statement.bindStringOrNull(13 + start, model.getCategoryId());
    statement.bindLong(14 + start, model.getFeedCount());
    statement.bindLong(15 + start, model.getReadCount());
  }

  @Override
  public final void bindToUpdateStatement(DatabaseStatement statement, Task model) {
    statement.bindStringOrNull(1, model.getId());
    statement.bindStringOrNull(2, model.getProjectId());
    statement.bindStringOrNull(3, model.getTitle());
    statement.bindStringOrNull(4, model.getDescription());
    statement.bindStringOrNull(5, model.getCollectionId());
    statement.bindLong(6, model.getPriority());
    Long refmCreatedAt = model.getCreatedAt() != null ? global_typeConverterDateConverter.getDBValue(model.getCreatedAt()) : null;
    statement.bindNumberOrNull(7, refmCreatedAt);
    statement.bindStringOrNull(8, model.getCreatedById());
    Long refmUpdatedAt = model.getUpdatedAt() != null ? global_typeConverterDateConverter.getDBValue(model.getUpdatedAt()) : null;
    statement.bindNumberOrNull(9, refmUpdatedAt);
    Long refmDueDate = model.getDueDate() != null ? global_typeConverterDateConverter.getDBValue(model.getDueDate()) : null;
    statement.bindNumberOrNull(10, refmDueDate);
    Long refmCompletedAt = model.getCompletedAt() != null ? global_typeConverterDateConverter.getDBValue(model.getCompletedAt()) : null;
    statement.bindNumberOrNull(11, refmCompletedAt);
    statement.bindStringOrNull(12, model.getCompletedById());
    statement.bindStringOrNull(13, model.getCategoryId());
    statement.bindLong(14, model.getFeedCount());
    statement.bindLong(15, model.getReadCount());
    statement.bindStringOrNull(16, model.getId());
  }

  @Override
  public final void bindToDeleteStatement(DatabaseStatement statement, Task model) {
    statement.bindStringOrNull(1, model.getId());
  }

  @Override
  public final String getCompiledStatementQuery() {
    return "INSERT INTO `Task`(`id`,`project_id`,`title`,`description`,`collection_id`,`priority`,`created_at`,`created_by`,`updated_at`,`due_date`,`completed_at`,`completed_by`,`categoryId`,`feed_count`,`read_count`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  }

  @Override
  public final String getUpdateStatementQuery() {
    return "UPDATE `Task` SET `id`=?,`project_id`=?,`title`=?,`description`=?,`collection_id`=?,`priority`=?,`created_at`=?,`created_by`=?,`updated_at`=?,`due_date`=?,`completed_at`=?,`completed_by`=?,`categoryId`=?,`feed_count`=?,`read_count`=? WHERE `id`=?";
  }

  @Override
  public final String getDeleteStatementQuery() {
    return "DELETE FROM `Task` WHERE `id`=?";
  }

  @Override
  public final String getCreationQuery() {
    return "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Task`(`id` TEXT, `project_id` TEXT, `title` TEXT, `description` TEXT, `collection_id` TEXT, `priority` INTEGER, `created_at` TEXT, `created_by` TEXT, `updated_at` TEXT, `due_date` TEXT, `completed_at` TEXT, `completed_by` TEXT, `categoryId` TEXT, `feed_count` INTEGER, `read_count` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))";
  }

  @Override
  public final void loadFromCursor(FlowCursor cursor, Task model) {
    model.setId(cursor.getStringOrDefault("id"));
    model.setProjectId(cursor.getStringOrDefault("project_id"));
    model.setTitle(cursor.getStringOrDefault("title"));
    model.setDescription(cursor.getStringOrDefault("description"));
    model.setCollectionId(cursor.getStringOrDefault("collection_id"));
    model.setPriority(cursor.getIntOrDefault("priority"));
    int index_created_at = cursor.getColumnIndex("created_at");
    if (index_created_at != -1 && !cursor.isNull(index_created_at)) {
      model.setCreatedAt(global_typeConverterDateConverter.getModelValue(cursor.getLong(index_created_at)));
    } else {
      model.setCreatedAt(global_typeConverterDateConverter.getModelValue(null));
    }
    model.setCreatedById(cursor.getStringOrDefault("created_by"));
    int index_updated_at = cursor.getColumnIndex("updated_at");
    if (index_updated_at != -1 && !cursor.isNull(index_updated_at)) {
      model.setUpdatedAt(global_typeConverterDateConverter.getModelValue(cursor.getLong(index_updated_at)));
    } else {
      model.setUpdatedAt(global_typeConverterDateConverter.getModelValue(null));
    }
    int index_due_date = cursor.getColumnIndex("due_date");
    if (index_due_date != -1 && !cursor.isNull(index_due_date)) {
      model.setDueDate(global_typeConverterDateConverter.getModelValue(cursor.getLong(index_due_date)));
    } else {
      model.setDueDate(global_typeConverterDateConverter.getModelValue(null));
    }
    int index_completed_at = cursor.getColumnIndex("completed_at");
    if (index_completed_at != -1 && !cursor.isNull(index_completed_at)) {
      model.setCompletedAt(global_typeConverterDateConverter.getModelValue(cursor.getLong(index_completed_at)));
    } else {
      model.setCompletedAt(global_typeConverterDateConverter.getModelValue(null));
    }
    model.setCompletedById(cursor.getStringOrDefault("completed_by"));
    model.setCategoryId(cursor.getStringOrDefault("categoryId"));
    model.setFeedCount(cursor.getIntOrDefault("feed_count"));
    model.setReadCount(cursor.getIntOrDefault("read_count"));
    model.loadPermissions();
    model.loadChecklists();
    model.loadMarkers();
    model.loadAttachments();
  }

  @Override
  public final boolean exists(Task model, DatabaseWrapper wrapper) {
    return SQLite.selectCountOf()
    .from(Task.class)
    .where(getPrimaryConditionClause(model))
    .hasData(wrapper);
  }

  @Override
  public final OperatorGroup getPrimaryConditionClause(Task model) {
    OperatorGroup clause = OperatorGroup.clause();
    clause.and(id.eq(model.getId()));
    return clause;
  }

  @Override
  public final boolean save(Task model) {
    boolean successful = super.save(model);
    if (model.savePermissions() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Permission> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Permission.class);
      adapter.saveAll(model.savePermissions());
    }
    if (model.saveChecklists() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Checklist> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Checklist.class);
      adapter.saveAll(model.saveChecklists());
    }
    if (model.saveMarkers() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Marker> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Marker.class);
      adapter.saveAll(model.saveMarkers());
    }
    if (model.saveAttachments() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Attachment> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Attachment.class);
      adapter.saveAll(model.saveAttachments());
    }
    return successful;
  }

  @Override
  public final long insert(Task model) {
    long rowId = super.insert(model);
    if (model.savePermissions() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Permission> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Permission.class);
      adapter.insertAll(model.savePermissions());
    }
    if (model.saveChecklists() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Checklist> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Checklist.class);
      adapter.insertAll(model.saveChecklists());
    }
    if (model.saveMarkers() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Marker> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Marker.class);
      adapter.insertAll(model.saveMarkers());
    }
    if (model.saveAttachments() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Attachment> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Attachment.class);
      adapter.insertAll(model.saveAttachments());
    }
    return rowId;
  }

  @Override
  public final boolean update(Task model) {
    boolean successful = super.update(model);
    if (model.savePermissions() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Permission> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Permission.class);
      adapter.updateAll(model.savePermissions());
    }
    if (model.saveChecklists() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Checklist> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Checklist.class);
      adapter.updateAll(model.saveChecklists());
    }
    if (model.saveMarkers() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Marker> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Marker.class);
      adapter.updateAll(model.saveMarkers());
    }
    if (model.saveAttachments() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Attachment> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Attachment.class);
      adapter.updateAll(model.saveAttachments());
    }
    return successful;
  }

  @Override
  public final boolean save(Task model, DatabaseWrapper wrapper) {
    boolean successful = super.save(model, wrapper);
    if (model.savePermissions() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Permission> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Permission.class);
      adapter.saveAll(model.savePermissions(), wrapper);
    }
    if (model.saveChecklists() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Checklist> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Checklist.class);
      adapter.saveAll(model.saveChecklists(), wrapper);
    }
    if (model.saveMarkers() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Marker> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Marker.class);
      adapter.saveAll(model.saveMarkers(), wrapper);
    }
    if (model.saveAttachments() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Attachment> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Attachment.class);
      adapter.saveAll(model.saveAttachments(), wrapper);
    }
    return successful;
  }

  @Override
  public final long insert(Task model, DatabaseWrapper wrapper) {
    long rowId = super.insert(model, wrapper);
    if (model.savePermissions() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Permission> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Permission.class);
      adapter.insertAll(model.savePermissions(), wrapper);
    }
    if (model.saveChecklists() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Checklist> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Checklist.class);
      adapter.insertAll(model.saveChecklists(), wrapper);
    }
    if (model.saveMarkers() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Marker> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Marker.class);
      adapter.insertAll(model.saveMarkers(), wrapper);
    }
    if (model.saveAttachments() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Attachment> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Attachment.class);
      adapter.insertAll(model.saveAttachments(), wrapper);
    }
    return rowId;
  }

  @Override
  public final boolean update(Task model, DatabaseWrapper wrapper) {
    boolean successful = super.update(model, wrapper);
    if (model.savePermissions() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Permission> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Permission.class);
      adapter.updateAll(model.savePermissions(), wrapper);
    }
    if (model.saveChecklists() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Checklist> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Checklist.class);
      adapter.updateAll(model.saveChecklists(), wrapper);
    }
    if (model.saveMarkers() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Marker> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Marker.class);
      adapter.updateAll(model.saveMarkers(), wrapper);
    }
    if (model.saveAttachments() != null) {
      ModelAdapter<Attachment> adapter = FlowManager.getModelAdapter(Attachment.class);
      adapter.updateAll(model.saveAttachments(), wrapper);
    }
    return successful;
  }
}
```

I managed to insert other columns in other tables and I didn't get the same error. For an example, the migration script I ran in my DataBase to insert the column "categoryId" was similar to this one:

```
@Database(name = ConstructDB.NAME, version = ConstructDB.VERSION)
public class ConstructDB {
  public static final String NAME = "construct_v3";
  public static final int VERSION = 22;

  @Migration(version = 21, database = ConstructDB.class)
  public static class Migration21 extends AlterTableMigration<UserProject> {
    public Migration21(Class<UserProject> table) {
      super(table);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreMigrate() {
      super.onPreMigrate();
      addColumn(SQLiteType.TEXT, "load");
    }
  }
}
```

This is the LogCat I received through CrashLytics:

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: categoryId (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT `id`,`project_id`,`title`,`description`,`collection_id`,`priority`,`created_at`,`created_by`,`updated_at`,`due_date`,`completed_at`,`completed_by`,`categoryId`,`feed_count`,`R`.`read_count` FROM `Task` AS `T` LEFT OUTER JOIN `TaskRead` AS `R` ON `id`=`task_id` WHERE (`project_id`='5716f387d07c5a887cf97c4b' AND `completed_at` IS NULL ) ORDER BY `due_date` ASC, `priority` DESC, `created_at` ASC LIMIT 2147483647
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:898)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:509)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1346)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1285)
       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.database.AndroidDatabase.rawQuery(AndroidDatabase.java:62)
       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.queriable.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:59)
       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.queriable.ListModelLoader.load(ListModelLoader.java:44)
       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.queriable.ListModelLoader.load(ListModelLoader.java:15)
       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.queriable.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:53)
       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.queriable.ListModelLoader.load(ListModelLoader.java:37)
       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.queriable.ListModelLoader.load(ListModelLoader.java:15)
       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.queriable.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:36)
       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.queriable.ListModelLoader.load(ListModelLoader.java:25)
       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.language.BaseModelQueriable.queryList(BaseModelQueriable.java:61)
       at com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.language.Where.queryList(Where.java:236)
       at com.construct.v2.db.dao.TaskDao.read(TaskDao.java:39)
       at com.construct.v2.providers.TaskProvider.readCached(TaskProvider.java:62)
       at com.construct.v2.providers.TaskProvider.read(TaskProvider.java:54)
       at com.construct.v2.viewmodel.entities.tasks.TasksViewModel.load(TasksViewModel.java:37)
       at com.construct.v2.viewmodel.entities.AbstractEntitiesViewModel.subscribe(AbstractEntitiesViewModel.java:76)
       at com.construct.v2.fragments.entities.TasksFragment.onViewCreated(TasksFragment.java:82)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1314)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Comment: When you add a new table you need to rebuild the database NOT sure how a user with the app would do that at development time you can I guess you could trap the error create a new temp table write all data from current table or tables to temp delete db recreate db write temp back to tables Best Design get tables configured FIRST and do not create new Columns

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I didn't create a new table. I added a new column to an existing one. Why shouldn't I do that?

Comment: Sqlite gets confused when you add a column to a TABLE so it need to reset hence you delete the db or do a lot of work to preserve the old data and write it back to the NEW DB check the SQLITE website and YES i understand you did not create a new TABLE

Comment: How can I delete the previous one and rebuild a new one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite Exception no such column when trying to select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337296/sqlite-exception-no-such-column-when-trying-to-select)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Amit. But I don't think it's a problem with my query. Since it works just fine when I uninstall the app and install it back again.

Answer (score 0):

Once you install app for the first time on your device, database will be created and if you change your database (change a column, add a column or add a table ...) and you have a previous version of app on your device, database will not change after installing new version. So if you want to change your database you need to uninstall previous version of app. if you have released your app to your users and you want your users don't lose previous version data, you have to migrate your database.

Comment: What is the technical process to migrate the db in DBFlow?