# How to fix 'SQLite No Column Exception'?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-package-managers, android-database, android-flavors

I am developing an android application that saves logged in user information in SQLite. But I am facing strange problem. In my DBHelper class create table function is created fine, insert function doesn't throw any exception but when I try to retrieve data from my SQL Lite DB it throws exception

> no such column: officer (Sqlite code 1):, while compiling: Select * from User where userId=officer, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)

I tried changing the database name and version many times but nothing worked. I tried to see database file from my android device to make sure if my table created fine but when I searched in Android/data folder of my phone all apps package names shows up there but my application's package name is not there.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CMDB.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_USER = "User";
public static DBHelper dbHelper;


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (dbHelper == null) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return dbHelper;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    createTables(sqLiteDatabase);
    Toast.makeText(App.context,"onCreate",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



}

private void createTables(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    try {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + " (" +
                "userId" + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + "userImage" + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                "userRole" + " TEXT NOT NULL," + "token" + " TEXT NOT NULL," + "userName" + " TEXT NOT NULL,"  + "userEmail" + " TEXT NOT NULL," + "userAddress" + " TEXT NOT NULL," + "mobile" + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );
        Toast.makeText(App.context,"createTables",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(App.context,ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    dropTables(sqLiteDatabase);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

private void dropTables(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);

}

public void saveUserToDB(User user) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("userId", user.userID);
        values.put("userImage", user.userImage);
     values.put("userRole", user.userRole);
        values.put("token", user.token);
        values.put("UserName", user.UserName);
        values.put("userEmail", user.userEmail);
        values.put("userAddress", user.userAddress);
        values.put("mobile", user.mobile);

        db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public User getUserFromDB(String userid) {
    User user = new User();
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "Select * from " + TABLE_USER + " where userId=" +userid+ "";

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            user.userID = cursor.getString(0);
            user.userImage = cursor.getString(1);
         user.userRole = cursor.getString(2);
            user.token = cursor.getString(3);
            user.UserName = cursor.getString(4);
            user.userEmail = cursor.getString(5);
            user.userAddress = cursor.getString(6);
            user.mobile = cursor.getString(7);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return user;

}

public void updateUser(User user, String userId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String userJson = gson.toJson(user);
    contentValues.put("user", userJson);
    db.update(TABLE_USER, contentValues, "userId=" + userId, null);
}

public void updateUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("userId", user.userID);
    cv.put("userImage", user.userImage);
  cv.put("userRole", user.userRole);
    cv.put("token", user.token);
    cv.put("UserName", user.UserName);

    cv.put("userEmail", user.userEmail);
    cv.put("userAddress", user.userAddress);
    cv.put("mobile", user.mobile);

    db.update(TABLE_USER, cv, "userId=" + user.userID, null);
}}
```

I expect the SQLite DB to be created with a user table and the mentioned columns. Also need to see the .db file in Android Device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite Exception no such column when trying to select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337296/sqlite-exception-no-such-column-when-trying-to-select)

Comment: You are using value in where clause as if it was a column name. add double quotes around it or use placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the exception you mentioned:

> "no such column: officer (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: Select *
>   from User where userId=officer, (OS error - 2:No such file or
>   directory)"

You have an error in the value for `userId`, i.e. `officer`.

Try adding a single quote before and after it, like below:

```
String query = "Select * from " + TABLE_USER + " where userId='" + userid + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post the complete error trace so that we can properly check the error. From the above code and explanation I can see one possibility the following query

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + " (" +
                "userId" + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + "userImage" + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                "userRole" + " TEXT NOT NULL," + "token" + " TEXT NOT NULL," + "userName" + " TEXT NOT NULL,"  + "userEmail" + " TEXT NOT NULL," + "userAddress" + " TEXT NOT NULL," + "mobile" + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
```

the key `userName` is not same as `UserName` in the code below

```
public void updateUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("userId", user.userID);
    cv.put("userImage", user.userImage);
  cv.put("userRole", user.userRole);
    cv.put("token", user.token);
    cv.put("UserName", user.UserName);

    cv.put("userEmail", user.userEmail);
    cv.put("userAddress", user.userAddress);
    cv.put("mobile", user.mobile);

    db.update(TABLE_USER, cv, "userId=" + user.userID, null);
}}
```

**Note:** Column name in DB is always case sensitive.